# append not working with hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to insert data from table a to table b (both are external tables), basically relying upon the append feature of the environment.  I have tried the same with managed tables as well, but the behaviour was same.

The append somehow is not working out for me. On the other hand, ther overwrite works just fine.

e.g. the following fails

```
hive> insert table page_view select viewtime, userid, page_url, country from page_view1;
FAILED: Parse Error: line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'insert' 'table' 'page_view' in insert clause
```

but, the following works just fine...

```
hive> insert overwrite table page_view select viewtime, userid, page_url, country from page_view1;
```

I am on hadoop 1.0.2 and hive 0.8.1

help needed...

insert table page_view select viewtime, userid, page_url, country from page_view1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe according to what I saw in the comments here (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-306) you are missing an **INTO** keyword.  I think something like this might work:

```
insert INTO table page_view select viewtime, userid, page_url, country from page_view1;
```